# Consolidated Notification email for scheduled builds in TeamCity

Tags: email, notifications, teamcity, artifacts, consolidation

Is there a way to consolidate the reports and artifacts generated across several test integration projects that run every night in TeamCity and send out just one email notification that links to all those build run summary/artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Composite build configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/composite-build-configuration.html) that will depend on all the builds you are interested in. The build result will have links to all the dependencies and there will be an overview of the results of all those builds. You will not have the artifacts in a single place, though, so you will have to observe each of the dependent builds. You can [configure your notifications](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/subscribing-to-notifications.html) to receive them only from the builds you are interested in - in your case, the composite build configuration.